# Hibernate @email doesn't care about domain or a FQDN

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

Using Spring Boot with hibernate. I have something like this in the poko

```
@Email
private String email;
```

These example inputs:

- fakeemail
- fakeemail@

I get the following error, which is expected:

```
email: not a well-formed email address.
```

However for this input:

- fakeemail@a

This is considered ok. Does Hibernate not care about the domain? (.com, .io, .company)?

PS: Using as of this date, the newest version here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.9.Final

Comment: `a` is an entirely legal hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fakeemail@a` can be considered a valid domain if you're sending an email to a local host named `a`.

In general, in the email validation, we accept more things that what would be strictly valid to avoid reporting errors for valid cases.

If you want to be stricter, you can add a regexp requiring a dot in the domain using the `regexp` attribute of the `@Email` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part)

> Valid email addresses:
>
> - simple@example.com
> - very.common@example.com
> - disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com
>   ...
> - **admin@mailserver1**
>   (local domain name with no TLD, although ICANN highly discourages dotless email addresses)

The most commonly seen dotless email address would be `localhost` (e.g. `root@localhost`).

However, if you're interested, you can make [your own custom @Email annotation](https://gist.github.com/php-coder/1616466)